# IS impact factor around 2 good for bio-engineering field?

Tags: bibliometrics

I need to Presenting an article as a lesson exercise with good impact factor, so i found this paper :

[**Sleep behavior assessment via smartwatch and stigmergic receptive fields**](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00779-017-1038-9)

With this [impact factor](https://www.bioxbio.com/journal/PERS-UBIQUIT-COMPUT):

[image]

With [this](http://mdanderson.libanswers.com/faq/26159) H index:

[image]

I googled the impact factor range for good journals, so i fond so things like [this](http://mdanderson.libanswers.com/faq/26159):

[image]

And somewhere i found some different acceptable impact factor different field like 3 for Civil Engineering and not acceptable by below 5 for medical sciences.

SO i asked here is around 2 IF Index is good in bioengineering and also there are any sites to index the Impact factor of publications based of filed of study?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to match your presentation to your audience.

Comment: Who gave you this exercise? Did they explain it in detail?

Comment: Can you just describe the relevant information on these pictures?

Comment: @user111388 it is as pattern recognition course exercise

Comment: @"henning -- reinstate Monica" those are the above paper's publication impact factor and H index , did this information answer your question?

Comment: @SoheilPaper: So this is kind of homework? Did the homework giver specify this task more?

Comment: it is not as a specified work but requested, but i am newbie int his part of work so i used the SE site to ask my question, also when the teacher and system refuse to answer my question because of saying asking to more!! (love SE Site!!)

Answer (score 1):

The go-to-place to look up Impact Factors (IF) is Web of Science's Journal Citation Reports (JCR). As it is a commercial product, you(r institution) needs a subscription to access it.

JCR puts journals into categories. In this case, *Personal and Ubiquitous Computing* is listed in the categories *Telecommunications* and *Computer Science, Information Systems*.

- In *Telecommunications*, the journal ranks 53 out of 88 journals in Web of Science 2018 (the latest available). The first-ranked journal has an Impact Factor (IF) of 22.973, the last one 0.350, the median 2.274.
- In *Computer Science, Information Systems*, the journal ranks 96 out of 155 journals. The first-ranked journal has an IF of 22.973 (the same as in the other category), the last one is 'not available' (the second-to-last is 0.282), the median is 2.170.
- There is no category called 'Bioengineering' in JCR, but there is one called *Engineering, Biomedical*. It contains 80 journals, the highest IF is 17.135, the lowest is 0.452, and the median IF is 2.272.

Using these three categories as benchmarks to assess the journal's IF, one can see that the journal is always close to the median value, and therefore certainly okay. But whether it is 'good' or not for the purpose of your exercise you need to ask your instructor.